# Showing hidden div

Tags: javascript, anchor, hidden

Case is;

I have 2 web pages..

1st page - Home

Home contains navigations (Home, Products)

Products navigation has a dropdown option.

List is: (Product1, Product2)

Both options are linked to the 2nd page using this code,

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'ProductItem', 
                                            'action'=>'index')); ?>#folio" class="imglink">Folio Plus</a>
```

result: it works well

2nd page - Products

Products dropdown menu is still present on the 2nd page.

Product1 and Product2  content is hidden so each products only appears when you select a product on the Product dropdown list.

PROBLEM: when i'm on the Products page and I select another product from the dropdown list the content of the page will not change, yet the url address now points to the product i selected..like;

when product1 is shown then i want to switch to other product say product2, the url address now points to product2 yet the content shown is still product1..

i used this code.

```
 var anc = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
    $('#' + anc + '.prod_cont').show();
```

any solution please?..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location.hash` instead to read and modify the hash. It should be more reliable since the browser will parse it for you.

Also, what your selector is selecting is something with an ID of the value `anc` AND the class `prod_cont`. An example of what it would find is: `<div id='someanc' class='prod_cont'/>`. You may have trouble if you had more than one div tag with that id since I believe jQuery will probably be translating that into document.getElementById which only returns one element. What I assume you are looking for is a structure like this: `<div id='someanc'><div class='prod_cont' style='display: hidden;'></div></div>` or something along those lines. The proper selector for that would be `'#'+anc+' > .prod_cont'` which should get all child elements with the class `prod_cont` inside of the element with id `anc`.

Comment: hi!..thanks for your reply..my main problem is if i'm going to navigate to the same page, the content which i selected does not show yet its url address now points to the item i selected.

Comment: i also tried using window.location.hash yet its still the same..=(